# Nginx Reverse Proxy Not Redirecting to Wordpress site running on non standard http port

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

So I am trying to setup a nginx reverse proxy in my network to only have 2 external ports out to the world. I am taking in both http and https traffic and using HSTS to force https. I am able to reverse proxy to applications running on the standard port 80/443, but when I try to reverse proxy to a application running on a docker host it gets weird. In the address bar it changes from fireampersand.ca/website to fireampersand.ca:8050/website. Im not sure why. Im still fairly new to nginx so maybe it is something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

nginx.conf

```
events {
   
}

http {   
   server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name fireampersand.ca;
    
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

      return 301 https://$host;
   }
   server {
    listen      443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name fireampersand.ca;
    
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fireampersand.ca-0001/fullchain.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fireampersand.ca-0001/privkey.pem";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;

    location ~* ^/owa { proxy_pass https://starscream.fireampersand.ca; }
    location ~* ^/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync { proxy_pass https://starscream.fireampersand.ca; }
    location ~* ^/ecp { proxy_pass https://starscream.fireampersand.ca; }
    location ~* ^/rpc { proxy_pass https://starscream.fireampersand.ca; }
    location ~* ^/portainer { proxy_pass http://docker.fireampersand.ca:9000; }
    location ~* ^/foodbank { proxy_pass https://docker.fireampersand.ca:8002; }
    location ~* ^/website/ { proxy_pass http://docker.fireampersand.ca:8050; }
    location / { root /usr/share/nginx/html;}

   }
}
```

Comment: to me it works, it gives 404 without any redirect

Comment: anyway the nginx configuration is ok, it's not making any redirect.. so it must be the application

Comment: good to know ill keep at it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Hmm, so i changed the port that wordpress is on for the docker container to 80 just to test and I get the 404 error now. The page is active as i can access it internally. Guess something else is going on.